# Form based product insertion

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I was wondering,if it is possible to create a html form in which you could pick an id pre-assigned to a product card and from there ,add a Title,description and image?

if it is possible ,I'd like to be atleast given some form of direction,because at this moment,I'm turning up a blank,results-wise.

Comment: Have you tried doing a google search? It should be easy to find examples in javascript.

Comment: @MikeTung oh,well I basically don't have any knowledge with it,so idk exactly where to look,since this is sort of a rushed project so I can't afford to learn everything right now .

Comment: Sadly here we don't offer help with this kind of problem as we can only help you objectively not subjectively